# Python/Pandas/Flake8: run code in import to extend DataFrame - how to avoid F401 unused import?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, flake8

I have written a module to extend a pandas.DataFrame with a custom extension using a file my_pandas_addon.py:

```
import pandas as pd
# some more custom classes & functionality here (...)

# and finally:
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("my_addon")
class MyAddon():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    def do_something(self):
        print("Working!")
```

In another file, I can now import this module and use my function right away:

```
import pandas as pd
import my_pandas_addon  ## <---- HERE: F401 'my_pandas_addon' imported but unused


def foo(df):
    df.my_addon.do_something()  # <---- here I am using my addon
```

This is pretty cool and works fine ... but flake8 isn't happy and complains that `my_pandas_addon` is unused. However, as the import registers my_addon, I am actually using the import - or, more accurately, the side effect of the import.

How do I deal with this problem?

a) simply by adding `# noqa` to the import. Works, but this seems a bit strange to me.

b) by adding a `register_plugin()` function to `my_pandas_addon.py` and performing the registration inside of that function. However, then I always need to `import my_addon` + call `register_plugins()` on the user side. But then I also need to ensure to register the plugin only once - while "only once" is automatically implied when it is run during the import.

So my question is: what is the best/most pythonic way to register a reusable pandas.DataFrame extension?

Comment: `"simply by adding # noqa to the import. Works, but this seems a bit strange to me."` probably less strange than abusing `import my_pandas_addon` just for its side-effect :)

Comment: On a more serious note, how about removing the decorator, then calling `register_plugin()` in the program entry-point? (**not** in `my_pandas_addon.py`)

Comment: Or, you could have an `__init__.py` file that could do all the registrations for you.

Comment: But where is my "program entry point"? I have no idea. Ultimately, you need to know at the very beginning of your program that you need to register the plugin. In all my test executables, all programs that might exist somewhere that include a function that in some sub-function makes use of my new plugin. Seems unreasonable. Also init does not solve any problem here (how?). In the end, a free function taking the df as first argument might be a valid work-around. So `my_plugin(df).foo()` instead of `df.my_plugin.foo()`. However, thats not so great in notebooks.